# How can i get image src from img tag in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to get multiple img src in a array form. i'm trying to upload multiple images at a time in a array form.

My jquery-

```
$( "#file" ).change(function() {
    if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {
        // send the formData
       var formData = new FormData( $("#formname")[0] );
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://localhost/JSG/blog/uploadimg',  // Controller URL
            type : 'POST',
            data : formData,
            async : false,
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
                  response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                  var html = "";

                  $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                    html += "<img  style='width:150px;height:145px' id='test'  src='http://localhost/JSG/upload/"+value.file_name+"' class='img-thumbnail'>";

                html += "<input style='display:none' value='"+value.file_name+"' type='button'  class='imgstr' name='imgstr[]'>";
                         });


                  $('#img_t').append(html);                        


            }
        });

    } else {
       message("Your Browser Don't support FormData API! Use IE 10 or Above!");
    }
      });
```

When i'm using input tag in below img tag its show error.

error in console-

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**
```

HTML-

```
<img style="width:150px;height:145px" src="http://localhost/JSG/upload/roundicons34.png" class="img-thumbnail">
<img style="width:150px;height:145px" src="http://localhost/JSG/upload/roundicons34.png" class="img-thumbnail">
<img style="width:150px;height:145px" src="http://localhost/JSG/upload/roundicons34.png" class="img-thumbnail">
```

Comment: add a class to images to capture their src, create an array in your javascript, and do a $(".img_class").each(function() {}); inside the function use the .attr() method to get the src attribute and then add it to the array

Comment: i'm facing two problem first is error message i mention in above code and second is get src from img tag ?

Comment: To the right of the error in your console it should tell you the file in which the error occurred, click that file link, it'll show you the line on which it occurred. Tell us which line it was.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get image src

```
  var image_src = $('img.img-thumbnail').attr('src');
```

Comment: Won't work, you're implying there's an `img` element inside an element of class `.img-thumbnail`

Comment: Aside from the above, `src` should be in quotes.

Comment: Try this `var image_src = $('img.img-thumbnail').attr(src);`

Comment: Still not correct as of the edit. The space between `img` and `img-thumbnail` is significant as it implies a parent > child selector.

Comment: my ignorance..apologies

Answer (score 0):

For html

```
<img src="my_path.png" class="retrieve">
<img src="my_path_2.png" class="retrieve">
```

JQuery

```
var attr = "";
$(".retrieve").each(function() {
    attr = $(this).attr("src");
    //insert the attr into your array
});
```